# Расположить блок с помощью flex-box

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, flexbox

Нужно расположить иконки справа как на картинке[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

они же располагаются с права но не становятся напротив текста, а выдавливают его, как бы отдельным блоком, нужно как то расположить их напротив друг друга с помощью флекса если это возможно.

```css
.content-center{
    background: url(../img/background_top.png) no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 640px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    display: flex;
    align-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    
}
.content-centr-top{
    display: flex;
    align-content: space-between;
    
    flex-direction: column;
    align-self :flex-end;
}

.ico-soc{
 
   
}
.a-img-ctr{
   
    align-self :flex-end; 
}

.h2-center{
    margin-top: 95px;
    font-size: 3.75em;
    color: #454545;
    font-weight: 600;

}
.h3-center{
    font-size: 2.25em;
    color: #464646;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.red{
    color: red;
}
.input-center{
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding: 22px 63px 22px 63px;
    border: none;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #636b92, #5f2f6a);
    border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    -ms-border-radius: 30px;
    -o-border-radius: 30px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #707070;
    transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -moz-transition: 0.6s;
    -ms-transition: 0.6s;
    -o-transition: 0.6s;
}
.input-center:hover{
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px #87a2da;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px #87a2da;
     box-shadow: 0 20px 20px #87a2da;
    
     
}
.img-centr,
.input-center:active,
.sing-up:active {
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 10px -1px;
    
}
.img-center{
    margin-right: 20px;
    background: #6D4A70;
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.input-img-center{
     display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,600,600i,900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <title>Securiti</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
     
      <header class="content-center">
          
                  <a class="a-img-ctr"  href="#"><img class="img-soc"  src="img/ico-g.png" alt="1"></a>
                  <a class="a-img-ctr" href="#"><img class="img-soc"  src="img/ico-f.png" alt="2"></a>
                  <a class="a-img-ctr"  href="#"><img class="img-soc"  src="img/ico-tw.png" alt="3"></a>
           
        <div class="h-content">
        <h2 class="h2-center"> Secure Email Communication  </h2> 
        <h3 class="h3-center"> Based in <span class="red">Somewhere</span>  </h3>
      </div>
     <div class="input-img-center">
          <input class="input-center" type="submit" value="Create account"/>
          <div class="input-img-center">
            <a href="#" class="img-center"><img class="img-a" src="img/img-apple.png" alt="#"></a>
            <a href="#" class="img-center"><img  class="img-a" src="img/img-play.png" alt="#"></a>
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Нужно эти иконки засунуть в обертку и спозиционировать их `absolute` к правому верхнему краю

Comment: это макет на картинке или есть такой сайт?

Comment: @Kirill, если ответ вам помог, отметьте его как ответ

Answer (score 2):

Нужно родительскому блоку `.content-center` задать `position: relative`, а блок с иконками спозиционировать абсолютно `position: absolute`, а также прижать его к верху `top: 0` и правому краю `right: 0`

```css
.content-center{
    background: url(../img/background_top.png) no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 640px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    display: flex;
    align-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper_a {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.content-centr-top{
    display: flex;
    align-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-self :flex-end;
}

.h2-center{
    margin-top: 95px;
    font-size: 3.75em;
    color: #454545;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;

}

.h3-center{
    font-size: 2.25em;
    color: #464646;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.red{
    color: red;
}

.input-center{
 margin-top: -10px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 padding: 22px 63px 22px 63px;
 border: none;
 background: linear-gradient(45deg, #636b92, #5f2f6a);
 border-radius: 30px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
 -moz-border-radius: 30px;
 -ms-border-radius: 30px;
 -o-border-radius: 30px;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 1em;
 cursor: pointer;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #707070;
 transition: 0.6s;
 -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
 -moz-transition: 0.6s;
 -ms-transition: 0.6s;
 -o-transition: 0.6s;
}
.input-center:hover{
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px #87a2da;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px #87a2da;
 box-shadow: 0 20px 20px #87a2da;
    
     
}
.img-centr,
.input-center:active,
.sing-up:active {
 box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 10px -1px;
    
}
.img-center{
 margin-right: 20px;
 background: #6D4A70;
 width: 46px;
 height: 46px;
 -moz-border-radius: 50px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
 border-radius: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-align-items: center;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}

.input-img-center{
 display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,600,600i,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <title>Security</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">

 <header class="content-center">

  <div class="wrapper_a">
   <a class="a-img-ctr"  href="#"><img class="img-soc"  src="img/ico-g.png" alt="1"></a>
   <a class="a-img-ctr" href="#"><img class="img-soc"  src="img/ico-f.png" alt="2"></a>
   <a class="a-img-ctr"  href="#"><img class="img-soc"  src="img/ico-tw.png" alt="3"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="h-content">
   <h2 class="h2-center"> Secure Email Communication  </h2> 
   <h3 class="h3-center"> Based in <span class="red">Somewhere</span>  </h3>
  </div>

  <div class="input-img-center">
   <input class="input-center" type="submit" value="Create account"/>
   <div class="input-img-center">
    <a href="#" class="img-center"><img class="img-a" src="img/img-apple.png" alt="#"></a>
    <a href="#" class="img-center"><img  class="img-a" src="img/img-play.png" alt="#"></a>
   </div>
  </div> <!-- .input-img-center -->

 </header>

</div> <!-- .wrapper -->

</body>

</html>
```